# Can not load the json file of urls in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I tried to make a dict with python , I try to retrieve data via the url however json error what is wrong ? I use python 2.7.6

```
import json
import urllib

json_string = 'http://localhost/csv/taxo.json'
parsed_json = json.loads(json_string)
print(parsed_json['genus'])
```

This error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "dic2.py", line 11, in 
>       parsed_json = json.loads(json_string)
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/**init**.py", line 338, in loads
>       return _default_decoder.decode(s)
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
>       obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 384, in raw_decode
>       raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
>   ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

Comment: `json.loads` doesn't download the json file from the url for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`json_string` is not a `json` string. It is simply a URL...

You should get the **content** of this URL with one of the HTTP modules that are available for Python.

You should do it the other way around. The `requests` module gives you the option to do a GET request and easily parse the response to a Python dictionary (given that the response is a valid JSON):

```
import requests

my_dict = requests.get('http://localhost/csv/taxo.json').json()
```

If you want to run this code you will need to install the `requests` module.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to get the content of the url, for example with **urllib** try sth like this, but it won't work for python3:

```
import json
import urllib

json_url = 'http://localhost/csv/taxo.json'
parsed_json = json.load(urllib.urlopen(json_url ))
print(parsed_json['genus'])
```

You should remember to change **json.loads** to **json.load** as the second one will also execute **.read()** method behind the scene, on retrived object, which is needed to correctly ready the data.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do this:

First download the webpage:

```
from urllib import urlopen
response_object = urlopen('http://localhost/csv/taxo.json')
```

After convert to string:

```
response_string = response_object.read()
```

Then convert to dictionary:

```
from json import loads
json_string = loads(response_string)
```